# format a word document

Tags: ms-word

I have written the index of my report in word document but the page numbers are not properly formatted, I even tried to use table for it but it is still not working .

TABLE OF CONTENTS

Chapter: 1 Introduction…………………………………………………………….…....……..1
1.1 Project Summary……………………………………………………….......………..2
1.2 Objective……………………………………………………….……….…….….........2
1.3 Scope…………………………………………………….…………………...........…...2
1.4 Technology and literature……………………………….……………………..2

like above i ve my index. In word document page numbers are not arranged in a line.kindly help me.

Comment: take a look at this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-table-of-contents-or-update-a-table-of-contents-HP001225372.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use instead of Whitespace button a Tab button.

And you may add a points "." at well. And numbers will be in true places

Comment: tab is not working when i press tab it points to the below line.